# Python : Mock a module that raises an exception

Tags: python, pytest, patch

I need to test a function in a module that import another module which raises an exception when imported.

```
#a.py
raise ValueError("hello")
my_const = 'SOMETHING'


#b.py
from a import my_const 

def foo():
    # do something with my_const 
    return "expected_result"  

#test_foo.py
def test_foo():
    from b import foo
    assert foo() == "expected_result"
```

Here when I import foo in test_foo.py, a.py get imported in b.py, an exception is raised and the import is never completed so my_const is not available in b.py.

I'm not allowed to modify neither a.py or b.py. Also, using `unittest.patch` and `@patch('a', 'my_const')`  does import `a.py` so it doens't work.

It is possible create the module dynamically with the import lib and add it to `sys.modules`, but is there another solution that doesn't require importlib ?

Comment: To clarify. 

Modules a.py and b.py are written by a third party and I'm not allowed to modify this part of the code. However, I need to write a test for foo in b.py, to do so I need to :

- import b
- call b.foo()
- chek its results

The first step fails, because b.py try to import a.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can create and importe the module dynamically. Here is a code inspired from the 
"Approximating importlib.import_module()" section in the [import lib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

```python
from importlib.util import module_from_spec, find_spec
import sys

def patched_import(name, **kwargs):
    spec = find_spec(name)
    m = module_from_spec(spec)

    for k in kwargs:
        setattr(m, k, kwargs[k])
    sys.modules[name] = m
```

Edit: My solution should be ok for a mock-up but be careful as manipulation of referential can have side effects.

To use it, just do:

```python
patched_import('a', my_const='stuff')
```

Before importing b.py.